# Multiple conditions in a jade conditional

Tags: if-statement, pug

I'm a bit stumped as to why... `if (data.query && data.query != '[object Object]')` works

but `if (data.query && data.query != ('[object Object]' || data.query != 'undefined'))`

How can you have multiple conditions inside of a jade `if`?

Comment: Have you tried adding additional parenthesis around both sides of the `or` statement?

Comment: Yes I have. I updated the answer to show that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking for `typeof` on the `data.query` for the `undefined` did the trick.

`if (data.query && data.query != '[object Object]' || (typeof data.query !== 'undefined'))`